# How to reschedule Quartz job scheduler in C# dynamically from database?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net

I have included Quartz.net library in my C#.Net website to send emails automatically based on some conditions. I have started the job to with RepeatForever(). I am getting the settings for the scheduler from database. Now when the job has already started is there anyway to check if the settings for the scheduler in the database have changed so i should also update them in my method so that scheduler runs with the new settings dynamically? So far I have done this:

```
public void StartJob()
    {
        var reminderSettings = GetReminderSettings();  //getting these settings from database
        var count = GetUnpaidInvoicesListCount();
        var intervalBtwnReminders = 0;
        if (reminderSettings?.RemindersGap != null)
        {
            intervalBtwnReminders = (int)(reminderSettings.RemindersGap);         
        }

        ISchedulerFactory schedFact = new StdSchedulerFactory();

        IScheduler sched = schedFact.GetScheduler();
        sched.Start();

        // create job
        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<EmailJob>()
                .WithIdentity("job1", "group1")
                .Build();

        // create trigger
        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x =>
            {
                 x.WithIntervalInMinutes(intervalBtwnReminders ).RepeatForever();
            })
            .Build();

        sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I wrote a set of methods to make it more easy.
You can't edit an existing trigger with your new interval, but you can replace your existing trigger with a new one.
The `CreateTrigger` method creates a new Trigger based on a old one and transfers the `TimesTriggered` count.

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a new trigger based on a existing trigger.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oldTrigger">the existing trigger</param>
/// <param name="startNow">indicates if the trigger should start immediately after schedule</param>
/// <param name="interval">the interval for the new trigger</param>
/// <returns>Returns the new trigger</returns>
public ITrigger CreateTrigger(ITrigger oldTrigger, bool startNow = false, TimeSpan? interval = null)
{
    var builder = oldTrigger.GetTriggerBuilder();
    if (startNow)
        builder = builder.StartNow();
    if (interval.HasValue)
        builder = builder.WithSimpleSchedule(s => s
            .WithInterval(interval.Value)
            .RepeatForever());

    var newTrigger = builder.Build();
    var simpleTrigger = newTrigger as ISimpleTrigger;
    if(simpleTrigger != null)
    {
        var trigger = oldTrigger as ISimpleTrigger;
        if (trigger != null)
            simpleTrigger.TimesTriggered = trigger.TimesTriggered;
    }

    return newTrigger;
}
```

**How to use it**

In this example, the Scheduler is already running.

```
// get the trigger
var trigger = Scheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey("trigger1", "group1"));

// get your settings and set the interval
var reminderSettings = GetReminderSettings();
var intervalBtwnReminders = 0;
if (reminderSettings?.RemindersGap != null)
{
    intervalBtwnReminders = (int)(reminderSettings.RemindersGap);         
}

// reschedule the job with a new trigger and start it immediately.
// if you don't want that it starts now, pass 'false' for the 'startNow' parameter
Scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.Key, CreateTrigger(trigger, true, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intervalBtwnReminders)));
```

Comment: I didn't get it, can you please explain your solution a little bit more? Where to make a call to the database for the settings?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem I added some more explanations, renamed the parameter `timespan` to `interval` to make it more clear. And added a doc header. I hope it's now more understandable.

Comment: Where should i use GetTrigger(), after the old trigger has started ( sched.Start() ) or after ( sched.ScheduleJob(job, trigger) )?

Comment: @Harry.Naeem None of that. You only need one Scheduler for your application. The method `StartJob()` (which is suboptimal named) should only register your Jobs/Triggers and start the Scheduler. Then you need to remember the scheduler as reference, somewhere where you can easily access it. Let's assume you executed `StartJob()` and maybe 5 minutes later, you call the example.

Comment: thank you mate, this worked like a charm! The most important statement in your last comment was **Then you need to remember the scheduler as reference**, which helped me solve my problem.

Comment: @Rabban So Quartz.net doesn't allow people to edit existing schedule job. But can it get the method that schedule going to perform? Like all you need to do is query to the jobId/Name or something then input new schedule. I know this is an old post but I hope you can reply to me.

Comment: @FaizEming I am not sure that i understand you. But with the example above you can easily use an existing job and execute it with a different trigger. If this does not answer your question, please open a new question and reword it to make it more clear. You can also refer to this question here.