# Quartz.net trigger doesn't fire

Tags: quartz.net

I have two tasks. The first should be execute once an hour, and the second every day at 12:00. The trigger of the first task works fine, but the second fires only if it is created a few minutes before the target time. What am I doing wrong?

**The configuration of the first:**

```
IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<WatchJob>()
    .WithIdentity("Job_1", "First")
    .WithDescription("Job_1_First")
    .UsingJobData("AppData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Job_1_First"))
    .Build();

ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("Trigger_1", "First")
    .StartNow()
    .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
    .WithIntervalInMinutes(1440)
    .RepeatForever())
    .Build();
```

**And the second:**

```
    IJobDetail updateJob = JobBuilder.Create<UpdateJob>()
        .WithIdentity("Job_1", "Second")
        .WithDescription("Job_1_Second")
        .UsingJobData("AppData", JsonConvert.SerializeObject("Job_1_Second"))
        .Build();

    ITrigger updateTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
        .WithIdentity("Trigger_1", "Second")
        .WithDailyTimeIntervalSchedule
            (t => t
                .WithIntervalInHours(24)
                .OnEveryDay()
                .StartingDailyAt(TimeOfDay.HourAndMinuteOfDay(12, 0))
            )
        .Build();
```

**Scheduler configuration:**

```
<quartz>
  <add key="quartz.scheduler.instanceName" value="Test" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.SimpleThreadPool, Quartz" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadCount" value="1" />
  <add key="quartz.threadPool.threadPriority" value="2" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold" value="60000" />
  <add key="quartz.jobStore.type" value="Quartz.Simpl.RAMJobStore, Quartz" />
</quartz>
```

Comment: Which version of quartz do you use? Is it an Asp.Net project?

Comment: @Rabban, i use Quartz 2.4.1 in console application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems nothing wrong with your Trigger definition. But Quartz(2.x) is not so well written under the hood and can sometimes act really strange.
Your second Trigger is a CronTrigger and can defined in an other way.

This works for me:

```
 ITrigger updateTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
    .WithIdentity("Trigger_1", "Second")
    .WithSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.DailyAtHourAndMinute(12, 0))
    // this line tells quartz to start the trigger immediately, you can remove it, if you don't want this behaviour
    .StartAt(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)) 
    .Build();
```