# How to run method on Job/thread Creation?

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I am new to Quartz, and I have been reading the documentation but I couldn't find what I need.

I have several jobs that we schedule/run with Quartz, and I would like to tell it to run a method when it creates a new thread for a Job.

The code I want to run is generic and I need to run it during the thread start.

I understand that I could achieve what I want if I create a JobBase class with my code and have all my Jobs inherit from it; but since this would require several modifications and this code is not really concern of the Jobs I was wondering if there is some feature in Quartz that would allow me to accomplish what I need without modifying them.

Can you tell Quartz to run a method when it creates a Thread/Job during the thread start?

Comment: In Quartz 2.x the scheduler creates a defined count of threads when it starts. There is no way to execute a method on thread start, but you can use a job factory and execute there your code when a job is created. Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158004/6666799) to see how you can create a job factory.

Answer (score 0):

Implement `IJobListener` or extend `JobListenerSupport` and implement or override the `JobToBeExecuted` method. As explained [here](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-2.x/tutorial/trigger-and-job-listeners.html), register your listener each time you application runs.