# Unable to create job with trigger with Quartz.NET

Tags: c#, quartz.net

I've got a .NET Core 3 worker service that uses Quartz.NET to schedule jobs. In this cut down example I have a single job with a single trigger. It doesn't seem to run and I don't get any exceptions.

- How do I debug Quartz.NET and get a list of jobs and triggers?
- Why isn't the job in the example below running?

I've tried creating the job and trigger within a group and without a group with no effect.

```
public class Worker : BackgroundService
{
    private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
    private readonly ISchedulerFactory _schedulerFactory;

    public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger, ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
    }

    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        NameValueCollection props = new NameValueCollection
        {
            { "quartz.serializer.type", "binary" }
        };

        StdSchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory(props);

        IScheduler schedulder = await factory.GetScheduler().ConfigureAwait(false);
        await schedulder.Start().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var pingJob = JobBuilder.Create<PingJob>()
            .WithIdentity("ping-job")
            .Build();

        ITrigger pingJob1Trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
            .WithIdentity("ping-job")
            .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
                .WithInterval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                .RepeatForever())
            .StartNow()
            .Build();

        await schedulder.ScheduleJob(pingJob, pingJob1Trigger, stoppingToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

The job:

```
public class PingJob : IJob
{
    private readonly ILogger<PingJob> _logger;

    public PingJob(ILogger<PingJob> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Ping");


        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quartz will create jobs using the default parameterless constructor. Set a breakpoint in your current `PingJob` construcor, start the debugger and observe that the breakpoint won't be hit.

Here is the relevant part of the documentation which describes this behaviour:

> When a trigger fires, the Job it is associated to is instantiated via
>   the JobFactory configured on the Scheduler. The default JobFactory
>   simply activates a new instance of the job class. You may want to
>   create your own implementation of JobFactory to accomplish things such
>   as having your application’s IoC or DI container produce/initialize
>   the job instance.
>
> See the IJobFactory interface, and the associated Scheduler.SetJobFactory(fact) method.

Now add a parameterless constructor

```
public PingJob() 
{ 
}
```

set a breakpoint in it, start the debugger and it will be hit. You can also set a breakpoint in the `Execute` Method and it will be hit now also.

You can now replace the `Execute` method as follows and it will print `Ping` on the console:

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
{
    await Console.Out.WriteLineAsync("Ping");
}
```

How can we get your orginial code to work? As the documentation says we need to use `JobFactory`. See for example the stackoverflow question [.net Core Quartz Dependency Injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157775/net-core-quartz-dependency-injection)

Comment: I'm already using a library to setup Quartz.NET to use DI though.

Comment: Which library do you use for that? Can you post the code where you configure your DI container and where you setup Quartz.NET?

Comment: @user9993 Marius is right, you need your own implementation of the `IJobFactory`, Quartz swallows exception when they occur and in the standard configuration, which you use, you can't see whats wrong. I wrote an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42158004/6666799) to a similar question, maybe it will help you to solve your problem.