# Unable to map dependency injection

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, dependencies, quartz.net

Please go through the below scenario. This is based on C# .Net Web API.

I have to call `GetMonthlyData()` which is located in BL layer. BL Layer related dependencies are initialized in the Controller and it works fine.
It is required to call the same `GetMonthlyData()` as a Job and I am using [Quartz](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) for that. However when initiating the Job I am getting an issue since the dependencies are not resolved at that time since the call does not goes through the controller. How can I resolve this issue?

FileProcessController.cs -> This is the controller which initiates the Dependency Injection

```
[RoutePrefix("api/FileProcess")]
public class FileProcessController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IFileProcessManager _fileProcessManager;

    public FileProcessController(IFileProcessManager fileProcessManager)
    {
        this._fileProcessManager = fileProcessManager;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("MontlyData")]
    public MonthlyProcessDataDM GetMonthlyData()
    {
        try
        {
            var result = this._fileProcessManager.GetMonthlyData();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ExceptionStatusCode.ThrowHttpErrorResponseAndMessage(ex);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

FileProcessManager.cs -> This contains the implementation of `GetMonthlyData()`

```
public class FileProcessManager : IFileProcessManager
{

    public FileProcessManager(IFileProcessManagerRepo ifileProcessManagerRepo)
    {
    }

    public MonthlyProcessDataDM GetMonthlyData()
    {
      //Code to be executed
    }
 }
```

Interface IFileProcessManager

```
public interface IFileProcessManager
{
   MonthlyProcessDataDM GetMonthlyData();
}
```

Execution of the above flow works properly. In the next scenario, I need to call `GetMonthlyData()` using Quartz. For that

Global.asax.cs

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        System.Web.Http.GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        JobScheduler.Start(); // This is the scheduler for the above mentioned job.
    }
```

JobScheduler.cs

```
public class JobScheduler
{
    public static void Start()
    {
        IScheduler scheduler = StdSchedulerFactory.GetDefaultScheduler();
        scheduler.Start();

        IJobDetail job = JobBuilder.Create<MonthlyProcessManager>().Build(); // This is the Implementation

        ITrigger trigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
       .WithIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
       .StartNow()
       .WithSimpleSchedule(x => x
           .WithIntervalInSeconds(10)
           .RepeatForever())
       .Build();

        scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trigger);
    }
}
```

I tried to implement as below to resolve the dependency injection, However it throws null reference exception pointing the dependency injection code.

MonthlyProcessManager.cs

```
public class MonthlyProcessManager : Quartz.IJob
{

    public IFileProcessManager _fileProcessManager;

    public MonthlyProcessManager(IFileProcessManager fileProcessManager)
    {
        _fileProcessManager = fileProcessManager;

    }

    public void Execute(Quartz.IJobExecutionContext context)
    {
        MonthlyProcessDataDM monthlyProcessDataVM = _fileProcessManager.GetMonthlyData();
    }
}
```

How can I resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which line are you getting exception and share the complete exception details

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157775/net-core-quartz-dependency-injection you can use a factory to inject into the quartz job.

Comment: You should probably upgrade to Quartz 3.1 and start using the [built-in dependency injection support](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html).