# How to use added scheduler using DI in Quartz.net

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, quartz.net

I have added scheduler in Startup of service like:

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
{
    q.SchedulerId = "S1";
    q.SchedulerName = "S1";
    
    q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();

    q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
    {
        s.UseProperties = true;
        s.UsePostgres("ConnectionString");
      
        s.UseJsonSerializer();
    });
})
```

Now I am tring to use this created Scheduler via DI like:

```
public SchedulerStartup(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
{
    this.schedulerFactory = schedulerFactory;
}

public async Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Scheduler = await schedulerFactory.GetScheduler("S1", cancellationToken);
    
    await Scheduler.Start(cancellationToken);
}
```

But somehow `Scheduler` is null. I wont able to access created Scheduler in startup configuration (`S1`).

Link: https://www.quartz-scheduler.net/documentation/quartz-3.x/packages/microsoft-di-integration.html#di-aware-job-factories

Comment: What interface class did you use to implement? You can read this post, it may be helpful to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42157775/net-core-quartz-dependency-injection

Comment: Just call GetScheduler without specifying the ID, it will return the one and only you've configured.

Comment: Here I have missed `services.AddQuartzHostedService()` to start scheduler using Hosting Service. Additional startup class not required. @MarkoLahma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have missed `services.AddQuartzHostedService()` to start scheduler using Hosting Service. Additional startup class not required.

This should be like this:

```
services.AddQuartz(q =>
 {
     q.SchedulerName = "S1";

     q.UseMicrosoftDependencyInjectionJobFactory();
     
     q.UsePersistentStore(s =>
     {
         s.UseProperties = true;
         s.UsePostgres(DbConnectionString);
         s.UseJsonSerializer();
     });
 });

 services.AddQuartzHostedService(options =>
 {
     options.WaitForJobsToComplete = true;
 });
```

Later created instance of this `Scheduler` can be used as (`S1`):

```
public MyRuntimeScheduler(ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory)
{
     Scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler("S1").GetAwaiter().GetResult();
}
```