# Create and schedule jobs at runtime in .Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, quartz.net, hangfire

I want to create a Report Scheduler to send the email with attach report automatically based on timings defined by User.

User can specify the Time and Occurrence of Report, once it is saved scheduler need to run on that specific time/day based on settings defined, also every user is independent to define its own settings.

I had taken reference from below SO answer

[How to reschedule Quartz job scheduler in C# dynamically from database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41589865/how-to-reschedule-quartz-job-scheduler-in-c-sharp-dynamically-from-database)

```
/// <summary>
/// Create a new trigger based on a existing trigger.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="oldTrigger">the existing trigger</param>
/// <param name="startNow">indicates if the trigger should start immediately after schedule</param>
/// <param name="interval">the interval for the new trigger</param>
/// <returns>Returns the new trigger</returns>
public ITrigger CreateTrigger(ITrigger oldTrigger, bool startNow = false, TimeSpan? interval = null)
{
    var builder = oldTrigger.GetTriggerBuilder();
    if (startNow)
        builder = builder.StartNow();
    if (interval.HasValue)
        builder = builder.WithSimpleSchedule(s => s
            .WithInterval(interval.Value)
            .RepeatForever());

    var newTrigger = builder.Build();
    var simpleTrigger = newTrigger as ISimpleTrigger;
    if(simpleTrigger != null)
    {
        var trigger = oldTrigger as ISimpleTrigger;
        if (trigger != null)
            simpleTrigger.TimesTriggered = trigger.TimesTriggered;
    }

    return newTrigger;
}
```

How to use it

```
In this example, the Scheduler is already running.
// get the trigger
var trigger = Scheduler.GetTrigger(new TriggerKey("trigger1", "group1"));

// get your settings and set the interval
var reminderSettings = GetReminderSettings();
var intervalBtwnReminders = 0;
if (reminderSettings?.RemindersGap != null)
{
    intervalBtwnReminders = (int)(reminderSettings.RemindersGap);         
}

// reschedule the job with a new trigger and start it immediately.
// if you don't want that it starts now, pass 'false' for the 'startNow' parameter
Scheduler.RescheduleJob(trigger.Key, CreateTrigger(trigger, true, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(intervalBtwnReminders)));
```

**Questions :**

Above code shows for rescheduling the job but i want to create new scheduler every time user saves.

what if two users defined same timing then also Quartz.Net work for both?

is there any better approach available or is there any performance issue with this approach?

Comment: I would recommend you to use , [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) it is backed with persistence storage ,means you can store scheduled jobs in `Sql server` database and it will trigger for every user as required.

Comment: @stom i had created sample application with Hangfire and look all of my requirements are fulfilled with this..thanks!!!

Comment: The referenced answer is from me ;) Why do you want to create a new scheduler every time? The scheduler is just like a advanced ThreadPool and you ignoring the idea behind ThreadPools. Threads are very expensive to create, i would think twice before doing this. There is also the possibility to persists your Jobs/Triggers and their state in a DB, so that you can cluster your executions on different servers.

Comment: @Rabban we had 100s of reports and user will define which report need to be scheduled at what time, each user has is independent of selecting his own report and timing,
Thats why we need to create new scheduler every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) solved all of my above problems